# Sort files with filemtime

Tags: php, sorting, filemtime

I have PHP file that generates gallery from a directory of images.

I want to sort images by modification date.

I'm trying to use filemtime function then sort function using the following code:

```
<?php
  $src_folder = 'gallery';  
  $src_files = scandir($src_folder); 

  function filetime_callback($a, $b) {
    if (filemtime($src_folder.'/'.$a) === filemtime($src_folder.'/'.$b)) return 0;
    return filemtime($src_folder.'/'.$a) > filemtime($src_folder.'/'.$b) ? -1 : 1; 
  }

  $files = array();
  usort($files, "filetime_callback");
              
  foreach($src_files as $file) {
   echo $file . ' - ' . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($src_folder.'/'.$file)) . '<br>';
  }
?>
```

And the output is like this:

```
image01.jpg - October 22 2017 19:40:02.
image02.jpg - October 22 2017 19:39:19.
image03.jpg - October 22 2017 19:39:23.
image04.jpg - October 22 2017 19:39:28.
```

It is not sorted by modification date.

How can I make my code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function scan_dir($dir) {
      $ignored = array('.', '..', '.svn', '.htaccess');
      $files = array();
      foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) {
          if (in_array($file, $ignored))  {
              continue;
          }
          $filemtime = filemtime($dir . '/' . $file);
          $files[$file] = $filemtime;
      }

      arsort($files);
      $files = array_keys($files);

      return ($files) ? $files : false;
  }

  $src_folder = 'gallery';

  $files = scan_dir($src_folder);
  
  foreach($files as $file) {
      echo $file . ' - ' . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($src_folder.'/'.$file)) . '<br>';
  }
```

Comment: It's just a similar concept, just taking the modification date as timestamp, putting into array and sorting it via arsort(), in order to get the desired result. The guy said that he is not a php dev, he needs just a solution and I hope this will help him, I don't think he is here to learn PHP from the bottom ...

Answer (score 0):

Variable scope is your issue,  `$src_folder` is undefined in the context of your filetime_callback function.

Do not disable error reporting on development environments.

---

Another problem is you aren't sorting the correct array.  You're creating an empty array $files then trying to sort that instead of the $src_files array.

Comment: Thank you, I've defined $src_folder in the context of my filetime_callback. It is not showing warning anymore, but it is still not sorted.

Comment: Ok... well you have multiple problems.  You're sorting an empty array...